# Webpack, public folder to different directory

Tags: php, laravel, webpack

If the Laravel project is in `c:\xampp\htdoc\proj` and the `public` directory is in `c:\xampp\htdoc\projpubl`, how can I set the webpack public directory?

```js
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', '../projpubl/js') //or c://xampp/htdocs/projpubl/js
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', '../projpubl/css', [
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('tailwindcss'),
    ]);
```

The command `npm run dev` still generates the `public` directory in the project root.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set the public path like the following.

```
mix.setPublicPath('../projpubl');
```